# Base64 string compress in client and decompress in server

Tags: javascript, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cordova

I am working in a camera enabled mobile application in which I have to take photos and upload. Although everything works fine but the uploading of generated base64 string takes too much time.

I am using cordova camera api to get the DATA_URL from camera, which gives the base64 string of the image captured. Using Rails to write the same image into Amazon S3.

Have also tried [LZ_string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) Javascript library to compress the base64 string but didn't get something in ruby to decompress.

Is there a possibility to compress the base64 string using Javascript and send to server ? Decompress the same in Rails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

For js you can use `btoa` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) or use one of the libraries, like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64) or just use you LZ_string.

In ruby you can encode and decode base64 using `Base64` [module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html)